# Java - Retrieving data from database based on user logged in

Tags: java, sql

If say, I logged in to my own website, I want to return data that **I** have submitted to the database. Problem is, how do I query the database to return only my data?

I understand that the query would like this using PreparedStatement:

```
select * from TableName where Username = ?
```

I want to add the parameter depending on who is logged in, not just 1 person. Sorry I know I might not explained it well, please ask if not clear.

**Edit:**
If I login, I expect the viewreports.jsp to show the reports I have submitted

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the username of all users logged in? Otherwise what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you need to find out who is currently logged in? Or do you need to get user data after having found out who is logged in? If the former, look up how to do session management in your web application framework. If the latter, look up how to do database access in your we application framework.

Comment: From where you will get the username? from a login form?. What are you using to make queries to database?.

Comment: If you login to a website, how could I query the database to only return data depending on who's logged in?

This data might be a report containing a title, summary, date submitted etc.

If I login, I expect the viewreports.jsp to show the reports I have submitted.

Comment: When someone logins, I store the username in a javabean - but I cannot create a new bean object or else it will erase it. Same problem with sessions. I can solve this problem using scriplets, but i'm trying to convert it to servlet if possible.

Comment: @Tom after successfully loginning in , you need to Place the username in HttpSession (request.getSession(false).setAttribute("username",request.getParameter("loginuser"));) and not in java bean

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is to:

- Add a column to all your database tables with
  an id or a name of whoever submitted
  it
- Alter your insert queries to write the name or id of logged in user
- Alter queries for all such tables to
  have one additional condition, which
  is if the logged in user matches the
  value from that column.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand. For example, if you login to my website, and you click to see what report submissions you have made, the website should display the reports that YOU have submitted and no-one else.

If I login, I only want to see what I submitted.

Comment: @Tom: Then I don't think you understood my answer, because it addresses *exactly* what you described now.

Comment: @Tom: I also think you didn't understand Goran's answer. I think the fact you're failing to appreciate is that the database has no concept of application users. It knows about database users, but that's not the same, and there is very probably one database user for your whole application. If you want the database to help you manage application users, you will have to teach it to do so by adding user columns to your data tables.